# Is it possible to define different icons for placeholders, components and edit frames in the Sitecore page editor "component navigator"?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.2

When working in Sitecore page editor, our editors navigate through the tree of placeholders, components and edit frames using the blue arrow icon to open the component navigator.
The component navigator shows each ancestor in the tree (from the context of the area of the page where the editor clicked) with a title and a small blue square bullet icon:

```
/sitecore/shell/~/icon/ApplicationsV2/16x16/bullet_square_glass_blue.png.aspx
```

Unfortunately, all components, placeholders and edit frames are represented by the same icon, and it isn't always easy to tell the difference between a component and a placeholder by title alone (edit frame buttons have an editable title and tooltip, in the core database).

Ideally, we'd like to have colour coded bullet icons that would help our editors understand where they were and what they were clicking on.

These aren't icons as used in the content tree.

So is there anywhere that I can set a different icon for each of these? If not, is there a code fix for this?

Edit for clarification: The blue bullets in this image - Body is a placeholder, the first Image Banner is a component, the second an Edit Frame (will get a new title), Banner Overlay is another placeholder:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to edit javascript files for chosen `ChromeTypes`.

Go to `sitecore\shell\Applications\Page Modes\ChromeTypes` directory. What you see there is base `ChromeType` function and inheriting functions like `PlaceholderChromeType`, `RenderingChromeType`, etc.

[image]

Edit the type which you want to change icon for. Override `icon` function like this:

```
icon: function() {
  return '/sitecore/shell/~/icon/ApplicationsV2/16x16/bullet_square_glass_green.png.aspx';
},
```

So if you edit `PlaceholderChromeType.js` file it should start like this:

```
Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeTypes.Placeholder = Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeTypes.ChromeType.extend( {
  constructor: function() {
    this.base();
  },

  icon: function() {
    return '/sitecore/shell/~/icon/ApplicationsV2/16x16/bullet_square_glass_green.png.aspx';
  },

  controlId: function() {
    var marker = this.chrome.openingMarker();
```

Clear your browser cache and refresh the page. Now all your placeholder icons will be green.

Answer (score 2):

These are generally configured under WebEdit; as defined in the "core" database. As an example, take a look under "/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons" after switching to "core".

You should be able to make most of the icon changes you require, from there.

Comment: Although, upon reflection, it might not give you exactly what you need. If this is the case, coming up with an answer will require slightly longer ;-)

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm not sure it will help - edit frame buttons have icons set, but these are for use in the content editor and the little floating button strip in the page editor. It's specifically the bullet points you see when you can navigate up to an ancestor I'm trying to get hold of :-)